# XML syntax highlighting not working despite explicit tagging

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I recently posted a question: [Supporting and testing multiple versions of a software library in a Maven project](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177190/supporting-and-testing-multiple-versions-of-a-software-library-in-a-maven-projec) in which I included some XML code samples.

I tagged the samples as XML code:

```
<!-- language: xml -->

    <foo>...
```

This hasn't worked and it looks like the Java highlighting is in effect. Is this an error on my part or a bug?

According to the [editing help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), "xml" is a [supported language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970). It certainly works fine on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<!-- language: lang-xml -->` is the correct syntax.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know why this is different from StackOverflow? The example I gave in my question would work on SO. Also, the editing help for Programmers [does link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to a [page which states "xml" is a valid choice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).

Comment: Oh wait. I guess this is because Programmers has no syntax highlighting associated with the "xml" tag?

Comment: @DuncanJones Yes. I always use the language selector instead of the tag selector, just to be sure.